# Issue when migrating from Piwik 1.12 to Piwik 2.15.0

Tags: upgrade, matomo

I've encountered the following error when upgrading Piwik from 1.12 to 2.15.0 by using the one-click installer:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Piwik_Plugin' not found in path_to_application/plugins/DoNotTrack/DoNotTrack.php`

How to recover my Piwik instance from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in the past a few times, succesfuly. I followed "major" versions at http://piwik.org/changelog/ and designed an incremental upgrade path.

In your case, this would be something like:

Piwik 1.12 -> 2.1 -> 2.2 -> 2.3 -> 2.4 -> 2.5 -> 2.6 -> 2.7 -> 2.7 -> 2.8 -> 2.9 -> 2.10 -> 2.11 -> 2.12 -> 2.13 -> 2.14 -> 2.15

Of course backup DB + code base before each one, make sure you're in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to follow the documentation from
http://piwik.org/faq/how-to-install/faq_18271/

--
I've also tried to run the following command without success:

`php console core:update`

After saving the database and the configuration file (`config/config.ini.php`), I've decided to checkout the latest version manually to recover from there.

`git remote add upstream https://github.com/piwik/piwik.git`
`git checkout -B 2.15.0 tags/2.15.0`

Accessing the dashboard worked but some panels were still not loading and also the following error message was logged:

`PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'path_to_application/libs/PiwikTracker/PiwikTracker.php'`

I had also to initialize the git submodules, to update them and to install the vendors using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

`# Download composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php 
php composer.phar install --prefer-dist --no`

`# Run the upgrade command
php console core:update --yes`

`# Disable development mode
./console development:disable`